# Persisting tweets using Spark Streaming

Tags: twitter, hdfs, twitter4j, apache-spark, spark-streaming

To begin with, our requirement is fairly simple.  When the tweets come in, all we need to do is persist them on HDFS (at regular intervals).

The 'checkpoint' API of JavaStreamingContext looked promising, but upon further review it seems to serve a different purpose.  (Also, I keep getting '/checkpoint/temp, error: No such file or directory (2)' error, but let's not worry about that for now).

Question:  JavaDStream doesn't have a 'saveAsHadoopFiles' method - which kinda makes sense.  I guess saving to Hadoop from a streaming job is not a good idea.

What's the recommended approach?  Should I write the incoming 'tweet' to a Kafka queue and then use a tool such as 'Camus'(https://github.com/linkedin/camus) to push to HDFS?

Comment: Why saving to hadoop from the Streaming job wouldn't be a good idea? I think that's what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Every time a message comes in if we save to HDFS would our solution scale?  Twitter sends millions of tweets per second. Inserting each tweet into HDFS directly wouldn't scale!  Would it?

Comment: If the write throughput of HDFS would not hold the sustained message write, how adding another system in between (like kafka) going to help?    Using a tuned window (x seconds) you can collect enough messages to write in a micro-batch to HDFS. That should be pretty efficient.

Comment: "A tuned window" is precisely what Kafka would provide to us, no?  Plus there are other benefits.  Storm & Spark streaming both are well integrated with Kafka for real time processing.

Comment: Kafka provides you a high-throughput queue, but it's another element adding complexity to the system. If your expected bottleneck is HDFS, I don't see how kafka can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this *awesome* blog entry that confirmed my ideas.  The author built a 'Forex trading system' using technologies such as Kafka, Storm, Camus. This use case is similar to mine, so I am going to use this design & tools.  Thanks.

http://insightdataengineering.com/blog/Building_a_Forex_trading_platform_using_Kafka_Storm_Cassandra.html

Comment: your architectural requirements are not quite well reflected in the question.

Comment: Alright, may be you’re right.  Here’s how I would map it:  I said, “To begin with, our requirement is fairly simple – write to HDFS”.  This is answered in the blog post in this section: “Data pipeline for batch aggregation service: slow”. It points out that they used ‘Camus’ – which is what I thought of as well. In future, Kafka/Storm or Spark Streaming would come in handy. Anyway, my bad!  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data from a DStream is by using the hadoop operations on the DStream:

```
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Duration(window))
val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(streamingContext,...).map(tweet=>tweet.toJSONString)
tweetStream.saveAsTextFiles(pathPrefix, suffix)
```

Assuming a constant input, the time window will give you control on the amount of messages to be processed each streaming interval.

Comment: I don't see a 'createTwitterStream' method on either JavaStreamingContext or StreamingContext.  May be it's only available in Scala? I am using 1.1.0 version of Spark Streaming.

Comment: It's called `TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, ...)`  I'll update the answer with the exact call.